# How to get data from a link inside a webpage in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I need to collect data from the website - https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/portal/?event=notificationsList&StartRow= and store it in a dataframe using pandas. For this I use the following code and get the data quite easily -

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/portal/?event=notificationsList&StartRow="

link = requests.get(url).text
df = pd.read_html(link)
df = df[-1]
```

But if you notice there is another hyperlink in the table on the extreme right hand side of every row of the webpage by the name "Details". I would also like to add the data from inside that hyperlink to every row in our dataframe. How do we do that?

Comment: beautiful soup packge is more appropriate to do such subtle operations

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Shi XiuFeng, BeautifulSoup is better suited for your problem but if you still want to proceed with your current code, you would have to use regex to extract the URLs and add them as a column like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/portal/?event=notificationsList&StartRow="

link = requests.get(url)

link_content = str(link.content)
res = re.findall(r'(<tbody.*?>.*?</tbody>)', link_content)[0]
res = re.findall(r'(<a href=\"(.*?)\">Details\<\/a\>)', res)
res = [i[1] for i in res]

link_text = link.text
df = pd.read_html(link_text)
df = df[-1]

df['links'] = res
print(df)
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you @aditya-k for your reply, but adding the link column was not the problem. The problem was how do I loop through the links to get some data from that link and add it to the initial dataframe. Please let me know any specific beautifulsoup components I can look into.

Comment: Why then you did not describe the actual problem in your question?

Comment: Apologies if it was not clear, but it was clearly written that we wanted to add data from the hyperlink. Also now I have made it much clear by adding "inside that hyperlink" to the question.